# Getting the left property of an LI element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic list of LI's inside of a UL.

I am trying to somehow be able to 'track' the last LI of the UL which has a class of Last.

I thought if I could test for the left property of the actual LI against some number, say -500, then I could do what I need to do.

The issue is I can't seem to get that property.

Is this even possible or does the parent (UL in this case) override that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about "tracking" the last one?

Comment: to Nick: I've got a slider type of function working whereby the ul list is loaded into a div with overflow:hidden. Previous/Next buttons slide that list and now I'm trying to figure out a way to make the 'next' button check to see if the last li is onscreen and if so, not slide. Since the whole list is loaded and only clipped, it's actually onscreen from load so :last wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `left` position relative to the page, you could do this:

```
var left = $('ul li.Last').offset().left;
```

Or relative to its parent, do this:

```
var left = $('ul li.Last').position().left;
```

- http://api.jquery.com/offset/
- http://api.jquery.com/position/

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Ztns/

Comment: I just tried:
alert($('#bottomUL li.Last').offset().left;);

and nothing happens?

Comment: @kelly - You would need to remove the semicolon from the inside of the `alert()` (just before the closing parenthesis).